# nil value after variable assignment

Tags: ios, swift

I have a VC that contains of textField and button. I have a simple task to pass textField text data to my model entity. However, while I want to assign textField data to entity data, my data remains nil.
I can't understand what have caused such problem

```
class InputTextViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var messageTextField: UITextField!

    //I receive user from parent VC by segue
    var userSendMessageTo: User!
    var tableView: UITableView?
    var message: Message { return Message(userSendMessageTo) } 
    // initialising object of my entity class

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(userSendMessageTo.name)
        //name is right
    }

    func createMessage() {
        message.messageText = messageTextField.text
        message.messageTime = Date()
        print(message.messageText) //nil
        print(message.messageTime) //nil

    }


    @IBAction func sendMessge(_ sender: Any) {

        createMessage()
        userSendMessageTo.mesaageHistory.append(message)

        print(userSendMessageTo.mesaageHistory[0].messageText) //nil
    }
```

My model

```
class Message {

    var messageText: String?
    var messageTime: Date?
    var messageInage: UIImage?
    var user: User

    init(_ user: User) {
        self.user = user
    }

}

class User {

    let name: String

    var mesaageHistory = [Message]()

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }


}
```

Comment: I think you meant `Swift` and not `Objective-C` for your tags.

Answer (score 2):

The construct `var message: Message { return Message(userSendMessageTo) }` returns a new Message object every time it's called.

Therefore you are creating a message object, assigning text to it, then throwing it away. Then you create a second message object, assign a date to it and throw it away. Then you create a third message object and check its text (which is nil) and then you create a fourth message object and check its date, which is also nil.

Try this instead:

```
class InputTextViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var messageTextField: UITextField!
    var userSendMessageTo: User!
    var tableView: UITableView?
    var message: Message?

    func createMessage() {
        message = Message()
        message!.messageText = messageTextField.text
        message!.messageTime = Date()
        print(message!.messageText) //won't be nil
        print(message!.messageTime) //won't be nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have declared `message` as a *computed variable*. This means that each time you reference `message` you are actually executing the following block of code:

```
Message(userSendMessageTo)
```

In other words, each reference to `message` *creates a new instance of `Message`*.

- `message.messageText = messageTextField.text` - Creates a new instance of `Message`
- `message.messageTime = Date()` - creates a new instance of `Message`
- `print(message.messageTime)` - create a new instance of Message, and its `messageTime` property is nil

There is no need to use a property here; your `createMessage` function should return the new `Message`:

```
func createMessage(withText text: text) -> Message {
    let message = Message(userSendMessageTo)
    message.messageText = text
    message.messageTime = Date()
    return message
}

@IBAction func sendMessge(_ sender: Any) {

    let message = self.createMessage(withText: messageTextField.text)
    userSendMessageTo.mesaageHistory.append(message)

    print(userSendMessageTo.mesaageHistory[0].messageText)
}
```

To be honest, if you create a proper initialiser for `Message` you could get rid of the `createMessage` function altogether:

```
class Message {

    var messageText: String
    var messageTime: Date
    var messageInage: UIImage?
    var user: User

class Message {

    var messageText: String
    var messageTime: Date
    var messageInage: UIImage?
    var user: User

    init(_ user: User, text: String = "", date: Date = Date()) {
        self.user = user
        self.messageTime = date
        self.messageText = text
    } 

}
```

Then your action method simply becomes:

```
@IBAction func sendMessge(_ sender: Any) {
    let message = Message(userSendMessageTo, text: messageTextField.text, date:Date())
    userSendMessageTo.mesaageHistory.append(message)

    print(userSendMessageTo.mesaageHistory[0].messageText)
}
```